# On form input focus, show div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form with an input (`#test`). Does anyone know how to, when in focus, display another div (`#tool-tip`) with jQuery?

```
<form>
    <div id="tool-tip"></div>
    <input id="test" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I bet you could have found this out by reading the documentation.

Comment: Indeed. All we're doing here is ensuring that this Stack Overflow question may manage to beat the proper jQuery documentation page in search results. Not good!

Comment: @Tomalak: actually a quite scary thought...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("#test").focusin(function() {
    $("#tool-tip").show();
}).focusout(function () {
    $("#tool-tip").hide();
});
```

Using [`.focusin()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and its opposite, [`focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: +1: Proper solution, working code, links to documentation. Good man.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks, no other way to answer `:)`

Comment: Tell that to the tens of thousands of authors of poor answers! Though I might downvote you now for that comma.