# Show/hide table table rows within a div when input focused

Tags: jquery

I'm using a table in a signup form and want to show the table rows within `<div class="collegeInfo">` when input id `"profile_higher_ed"` is focused. I found a few answers to similar questions on here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635437/on-form-input-focus-show-div). However when I adapted the jQuery it wasn't hiding the table rows when the input wasn't focused.

Here is the HTML produced by my form:

```
<tr>
  <td class="label"><label for="profile_higher_ed">College:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input id="profile_higher_ed" name="profile[higher_ed]" size="32" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
<div class="collegeInfo">
<tr>
  <td class="label"><label for="profile_major">Major:</label></td>
  <td>
    <input id="profile_major" name="profile[major]" size="32" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="label"><label for="profile_major">Grad Year:</label></td>
  <td class="select">
    <select id="date_year" name="date[year]">
      ...
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery I adapted:

```
$("#profile_higher_ed").focusin(function() {
    $("div.collegeInfo").show();
}).focusout(function () {
    $("div.collegeInfo").hide();
});
```

Is the problem that I'm using `<tr>` within the `<div>`?

Comment: It's not valid html to put a `<div>`between `<tr>` elements. Why don't you simply give your <tr> an id and hide them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `<div>` with the `<tr>` element in between is a problem (it's not valid).
I made a JS Fiddle for you. If I understand the problem correctly this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/cJRrx/5/

I put a class on the two `<tr>` elements and changed your jQuery a bit to be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.collegeInfo").hide();
});
$("#profile_higher_ed").focus(function() {
    $("tr.collegeInfo").show();
});
```

**Edit**:
You can also try using

```
$("#profile_higher_ed").live('focus', function() {
    $("tr.collegeInfo").show();
});
```

or

```
$("#profile_higher_ed").focusin(function() {
    $("tr.collegeInfo").show();
});
```

As an alternative to focus you can do the same thing with `.click()`. But since you're working with a form this won't be of much help if the user tabs through it.

**Edit 2**:
As pointed out in the comments it is better to use `$("selector").on('focus', callback);` nowadays, since `live()` is deprecated in jQuery.

Comment: This is great. I see it in the Fiddle working perfectly, but for some reason it's not working properly in my code. The `tr.collegeInfo` hides, but doesn't show when focusing. Any ideas why that might be? Since the `tr.collegeInfo` is hiding it isn't the jQuery...

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) `.focus()` can have problems in IE. Check this new fiddle, that has two other options: http://jsfiddle.net/cJRrx/7/. It uses `.live()` and `.focusin()` I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: If you have more problems, you can also update your initial post with the exact code you're using now. Also make sure that you edited your HTML to match what I have in the fiddle.

Comment: the `.live('focus', function()` worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: use `.on( 'focus', function(){} )` because `.live()` method is deprecated now in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that div.
Just add class collegeInfo to the rows ( elements) you want to hide and instead of  `$("div.collegeInfo")` selector use `$(".collegeInfo")`.